# how to get the height of an element and then apply that value through css

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get the height of my navigation and apply it to a margin-top so I can offset my banner. My navigation is fixed so I'm trying to compensate for that so my banner isn't hidden underneath.

```
// Offset Banner to Height of Navigation
    function bannerOffset() {

        var bannerTop = $('.x-navbar').height();    
        $('#banner-carousel').css('margin-top', bannerTop);

    }
```

This, I thought would do it, but it doesn't reflect anything at all in the front-end.

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var bannerTop = $('.x-navbar').outerHeight();
        $('.x-main').css('margin-top', bannerTop);

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var bannerTopScroll = $('.x-navbar.scroll').outerHeight();
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
                $('.x-main').css('margin-top', bannerTopScroll);    
            }
        });
    });
```

So I thought I had this, but on load, the margin-top of `.x-main` is `245px`. When I scroll it becomes `85px`. I can see the numbers go down to that. The issue is when I scroll back up to the top the value doesn't go back to `245px`. It's not very consistent, but I often get `144px`. I should add that, and this is probably why, I have another function that changes the height of my `.x-navbar` when `.scroll` is added to it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.x-navbar').addClass('scroll');
      } else {
        $('.x-navbar').removeClass('scroll');
      }
});
```

So I am not sure how to make this all smooth and working properly. If I reload the page the `.x-main`is back to `245px`. When I scroll back to the top it's not calculating properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. Maybe you want to use `$.outerHeight()` instead, your selectors are wrong, or you're experiencing [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

It's worth noting that `$.height()` returns an integer value, so in your `$.css()` line, you should change `bannerTop` to `bannerTop + 'px'` so that the CSS has a unit and not just a number... but it looks like jQuery is doing that automagically for me here. You might try it and see.

```js
var bannerTop = $('.x-navbar').height();
$('#banner-carousel').css('margin-top', bannerTop);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-navbar">x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br>x-navbar<br></div>
<div id="banner-carousel">banner carousel</div>
```

Comment: I tried outerHeight but that didn't work neither. My selectors are correct too. What was the "px" solution? I had refreshed and lost that answer.

Comment: @DarrenBachan If you give us a working example of your problem, we can help instead of just taking guesses. The "px" solution was saying that `$.height()` returns an integer value, so in your `$.css()` line, you should change `bannerTop` to `bannerTop + 'px'` so that the CSS has a unit and not just a number... but it looks like jQuery is doing that automagically for me  here. You might try it and see.

Comment: yeah I didn't catch that but thought Mike was right on the px thing when he posted it - it would help to see more code tho

Comment: I got it working, I didn't need 'px". My original code was right, I had it wrapped in a function but I wasn't calling that function anywhere so I switched it to a doc ready and it worked.

Comment: @DarrenBachan awesome. In the future, please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... and when you're creating that, in instances like this, you'll probably answer your own question.

Comment: Michael  Coker Instead of creating a new question, I modified my original to go more in-depth to what I'm trying to achieve.